# reading yml file in countries where decimal point seperator is , instaed of

Tags: c++, opencv, localization, decimalformat

I am trying to read yml file with opencv in c++. I can read it without any problem, but when my application runs in a country that decimal separator is ',' instead of '.', I am getting error as yml files has double fields.

How can I read yml file correctly on all countries?

Is there any way that I can to application that yml should be read using '.' as decimal separator?

### Edit 1

sample code:

```
    cv::FileStorage fs(filename, cv::FileStorage::READ);
    cv::FileNode MyNode = fs["MyNode"];
    std::vector<MyData> MyDataSet;
    cv::Mat tempMat;
    for (cv::FileNode item : MyNode ) {
        MyData myData;
        item["p1"] >> tempMat;
        myData.p1 = tempMat;
        MyDataSet.push_back(myData);
    }
    fs.release();
    return MyDataSet;
```

Comment: can you paste a code?